# How to remove spaces from variable/directories in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, whitespace

I have this bit of code:

```
find . ! -path . -type d -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -exec sh -c '
    dir="$0"
    tvnamer --batch $dir
    mv $dir/*.mkv $dir/..
    [ -f $dir/*.part ] || trash $dir
' {} ';'
```

However, it breaks because there are spaces in directory names in `$dir` (TVnamer gets confused).

```
./Show/Season/[ www.Torrenting.com ] - Castle.2009.S06E01.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION
./Show/Season/[ www.Torrenting.com ] - Revenge.S03E01.720p.HDTV.x264-2HD
```

How can I remove the spaces / rename the folders in `$dir` and then pass that to the rest of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes whenever you reference `$dir`:

```
find . ! -path . -type d -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -exec sh -c '
    dir="$0"
    tvnamer --batch "$dir"
    mv "$dir"/*.mkv "$dir"/..
    [ -f "$dir"/*.part ] || trash "$dir"
' {} ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

As @fedorqui said, it is a bug in your "bit of code" where it has not quoted the directory name.  However, to answer your question *How to remove spaces from variable/directories in shell?*:

```
dir="Program Files"
new_dir=${dir// /}
mv "$dir" "$new_dir"
```

The string substitution is supported in Bash and ksh93 (and maybe elsewhere).  `${dir// /}` means: take the variable `dir` and replace globally (`//`) the pattern *space* with nothing (the text after the final `/`).